# Flask-Admin link back to main site

Tags: html, flask

Is there any way to modify the home button url link on the flask-admin admin top panel so that I redirect back to a main site?

I can add a link in a custom.html page eg:

```
{% extends 'admin/master.html' %}
{% block body %}
    <a href="{{ url_for('main.home') }}">Home</a>
{% endblock %}
```

But this is hidden away inside the custom page. I'd prefer a top-bar link out of admin.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Easiest way is to add a menu link and leave the admin home page alone (you might want to add a dashboard or suchlike in the future):

```
from flask_admin.menu import MenuLink

# Create admin
admin = Admin(app, name='Admin', url='/')
admin.add_view(ImageView(model=Image, session=db.session, category='Database', name='Images'))
# Add custom link to public website home page
admin.add_link(MenuLink(name='Public Website', category='', url=url_for('main.home')))
```

Note, `url_for` needs to be called within a Flask application context. For example, if using the Flask application factory pattern, this would look something like the following:

```
def create_app(config):

    app = App('app')

    #  setup config

    #  setup blueprints 

    #  setup Flask-Admin

    from app.admin import create_admin
    from app.admin.configure import configure_admin
    with app.app_context():
        admin = create_admin(app=app)
        configure_admin(app, admin)

    #  more stuff

   return app
```

`__init__.py` in app.admin module

```
def create_admin(app=None):
    return Admin(app, template_mode='bootstrap3')
```

`configure.py` in app.admin module

```
def configure_admin(app, admin):

    # setup views

    # add link to home page

    admin.add_link(MenuLink(name='Public Website', category='', url=url_for('home.HomeView:index')))
```

Comment: `MenuLink` is now imported as `from flask_admin.menu import MenuLink`

Comment: I need to use `with app.test_request_context():
    admin.add_link(MenuLink(name='Public Website' category='', url=url_for('index')))` to get this to work

Comment: @alex_lewis - Thanks, added a note on calling within a Flask application context.

Answer (score 3):

You can override `get_url` method of `MenuLink`. That way you get around application context problem.

```
from flask import url_for
from flask_admin import Admin
from flask_admin.menu import MenuLink

class MainIndexLink(MenuLink):
    def get_url(self):
        return url_for("main.index")


admin = Admin(name="Admin")
admin.add_link(MainIndexLink(name="Main Page"))
```

```
def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)

    from app.admin import admin
    admin.init_app(app)

   return app
```

Comment: This is substantially cleaner then the above method

Answer (score 1):

If you are having issues with app context error when using app.app_context():

```
RuntimeError: Unable to build URLs outside an active request without 'SERVER_NAME' configured. Also configure 'APPLICATION_ROOT' and 'PREFERRED_URL_SCHEME' as needed.
```

You can simply 'test_request_context()' method.

```
with app.test_request_context():
    admin.add_link(MenuLink(name='Name', category='', url=url_for('home.home_route')))
```

This is documented [here](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.0.x/testing/#other-testing-tricks)